# How to improve app loading speed in custom ROM?

Tags: applications, settings, internal-storage, custom-roms, ram

I have installed Official Cyanogenmod 14.1 ROM on my Redmi 1s. I have installed only 20 user apps(out of 20,6 are google apps).I am facing app loading delay for some apps like dialer, settings, camera like that. It will take about 5 seconds delay to open up. Earlier, it was faster than this.

Steps I have done:

1. I install Night-lies as a fresh install(clears internal storage) sometimes, and restores some apps using titanium backup (Contacts, Sms, Whatsapp).
2. Sometimes, I will clear cache and data of major apps like Google, Gmail, Browsers etc
3. Prevents data usage for rarely used apps.

But, still it continues. How to speed up?

Comment: Don't expect SD400+1GB to handle Nougat too well...

Comment: @AndyYan Well, I have an "old" Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini, and it's perfectly able to handle Nougat. Is the device in question so bad, compared to mine?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman 1GB versus 1.5GB can make a noticeable difference depending on what app he has. S4Mini also has a MSM8930AB SoC with Krait 300 cores, and with many Android apps running on single core, I believe it's quite a bit superior. Although I do think 5s delay for a preinstalled app is way too much...

Comment: To OP: are there any _other_ Nougat ROMs available for your device that's _not_ based on CM, for example, Omni? Try one of those to see if it's a ROM-specific issue, or if it's just your device can't take it anymore.

Comment: Other Roms are available such as Resurrection Remix. I will have a try, and have an analysis whether it is Rom specific. .